# Flash execution looping - only take health away once per hit

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am just a beginner in Flash and I can't solve this.

**How do I make the actionscript execute only once per hit?**

This is my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
function loop (event:Event):void
    {
            for (var i:int = hBottleArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (runner.hitTestObject(hBottleArray[i])){
            health++;
            hBottleArray.removeAt(i);
        }
            }
for (var i:int = killerarray.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (runner.hitTestObject(killerarray[i])){
        health--;
        killerarray.removeAt(i);
        sign1.x-=40;
        tip1.x-=40;
        bg.x-=40;
        secretmessage.x-=40;
        healthbottle1.x-=40;
        killer.x-=40;
        killer2.x-=40;
        killer3.x-=40;
        platform.x-=40;
    }
}
    if (bg.x>327)
    {
        sign1.x-=40;
        tip1.x-=40;
        bg.x-=40;
        secretmessage.x-=40;
        healthbottle1.x-=40;
        killer.x-=40;
        killer2.x-=40;
        killer3.x-=40;
        platform.x-=40;
    }
}
```

RESULT:
Its a warning and another error in the output panel..
Warning 3596: duplicate variable definition.
OUTPUT PANEL:TypeError: Error #1006: removeAt is not a function.
    at ObstacleCourse_fla::MainTimeline/loop()

Please help how to solve

FOR **NEAL DAVIS** I use flash player 11.2 r2o2

Please take note that this is **not** my whole script

Comment: What version if flash player are you using? Is this an Air app? To use removeAt you need flash player 19 or later or Air 19 or later. If you are using an older version, upgrade or use `.splice` as per my comment regarding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the method I was talking about in the comments:

Let's say you have 3 health bottles called `healthbottle1` etc.

```
var hBottleArray:Array = [healthbottle1,healthbottle2,healthbottle3];
```

then inside your main game loop:

```
for (var i:int = hBottleArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (character.hitTest(hBottleArray[i])){
        health++;
        // any code you want to execute for when a health bottle is picked up
        hBottleArray.removeAt(i);//this removes the bottle from the array so it doesn't get checked again. This will stop your continued health increase. 
    }
}
```

That part with `for (var` is the start of a "for loop". You can google that. The other trick here is using an Array. Google that too.

Comment: so you're telling me that the for( var is the loop start itself? if yes, do I have to put it in the gameloop I made or not? I don't have to, right? And can I only use one element in the array ?I have a lot of questions but I thought health-- would decrease the number and not increase...Do I have to remove my healthbottle gameloop? I have a mixed up brain right now.. Sorry! Again!

Comment: Yes put it in the game loop

Comment: Yes you can have an array of just 1

Comment: Yes use health++. Sorry. Typo

Comment: But do i have to erase the if (runner.hitTestObject(healthbottle1))?

Comment: So you'll have a loop inside a loop. Your game loop executes once per frame. Your "for loop" executes once for each element in the array. If you only have one element in the array, it will just execute once per frame. If you pick up the health bottle, the bottle gets removed from the array, and the for loop will stop executing at all, so no more health++

Comment: @Oran153 yes. Erase that part

Comment: Okay I am gonna update my question and check for errors... >_<

Comment: wait wait wait.. removeAt? it says there is no such function as removeAt

Comment: At some point you may have a feature that allows the killers to be destroyed. So you'd do the same thing. Put them all in an array, loop through them with a for loop and anytime a killer is destroyed, remove it from the array so it doesn't get checked again.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#removeAt()  here is the help document on removeAt

Comment: The only reason I can think of that removeAt didn't work is if you didn't create an array or something. removeAt is a method of the array class. I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: So you are telling me to put all of the "killers" in another array (as of experiment)?

Comment: It would be handy. Basically anytime you want to do the same thing to a group of objects, put them in an array, and loop through the array doing that thing to each array element. That way you could have 30 killers on screen but only write what you want to do with them one time, not 30 times.

Comment: but do I really have to put removeAt? It is because it gave me the same output

Comment: You can use `hBottleArray.splice(hBottleArray.indexOf(hBottleArray[i]),1);` but doesn't that look worse? removeAt is a method of the Array class. I don't know why it isn't working. If you show your code that is having the problem I can help.

Comment: Maybe you are using an older flash player than version 19? If so that is why. RemoveAt was newly added to the library to make splicing single elements easier and faster.  I know this is being a headache but stick with it. It's a skill you will use everywhere in flash and most any other language you learn.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `visible` property as this doesn't remove the bottle or enemy (it is still there, causing the script to trigger every frame, you just can't see it)

Instead use `healthbottle1.parent.removeChild(healthbottle1);` or something along those lines.

What this does is remove the object from something called the display list. Google "AS3 display list" for more information on that.

You can do the same thing with the killers, but I assume you don't want them to disappear after they hit the player once. So instead you can have some sort of kick back mechanic that immediately sets the player back (enough pixels to make the enemy stop hitting him) or just make the player invincible for 1 second or 2 seconds. Many games implement that type of mechanic (classically with a visual flare of making the character flash during invincible period). If you choose one of those methods, give it a try and let us know if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Neal Davis I don't know how to do the invincible/invulnerable part of the player when it hits the killer... sorry, but may I ask that on how to?

Comment: I have also used the removechild thing and comes out like this in the output panel: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at ObstacleCourse_fla::MainTimeline/loop()

And it still continuously increases health no

Comment: Does your .visible part work as you intended? It disappears?

Comment: it did disappear but still increases the health

Comment: also thanks for the suggestion of moving the player back... Its helpful! :)

Comment: removeChild should work. Can edit your post and add the new code with your removeChild part? Thanks

Comment: Removing a child does **not** change it's x/y/width/height and the hit test will still succeed still.  Though if a child's parent(s) have their own x/y or scale the child will not be the same when removed as those parent positions will no longer be applied.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis oh right! That's what we're missing.  Thanks.

Comment: You can just add a criteria to the if statements (before the hit test for efficiency):  `if(healthbottle.parent && runner.hitTestObject(healthbottle){` - then if you remove child it won't keep running

Comment: I had to think, just now, "how do I usually do this then?" And I realized the method I usually use is to put that health bottle in an array and then iterate through that array to do my hittest, and then if I remove the bottle from the stage, also remove it from the array so I don't check it again. Does that make sense? @Oran153

Comment: nope... XD But I do know how this is complicated really... can someone just tell me what and where to put this code???? Thank you...

Comment: I am sorry but I think I am under beginner XD

Answer (score 0):

Ok @Neal davis Ill just put the bottle out of stage and the killers are fine without the arrays so thank you for your help!
Id rather learn the future answers in the future (Duh xD) and search them so I would avoid having a lot of questions asked here in stackoverflow... But its also useful for people to answer this question... XD THANKS!